# How to compute for the verification rate at 0.001 FAR?

Tags: roc

I want to test my pair matching method based on this evaluation metric but unsure how to do this? I only have positive (matching) test samples.

Answer (score 1):

If you have only positive samples, you will never be able to compute a false alarm rate because you don't have any negative samples that could be incorrectly labelled positive.

This is because FAR = FA / N = 0 / 0

with N = number of negative samples and FA the number of false alarm in your sample.

In other words, you will need to collect a set of negative samples if you want to compute this statistic.